# Hiding the formula in the selected cell

Tags: excel, vba, object, events, hide

[image]

[image]

I am having error in my code, it says in `.formula = TheFormula` (variable) is not set. Please help me to resolve this script. **I just want to hide the formula when I clicked the cell value**.

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
        Dim Rng As Range
        Static Cell As Range
        Static TheFormula As String
        Set Rng = Range("n4:o25")
         If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
          If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
            Cell.Formula = TheFormula
          End If
         Set Cell = ActiveCell
        With Cell
         TheFormula = .Formula
          .Value = .Value
        End With
       Else
        With Cell
        .Formula = TheFormula
        End With
       End If
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code. It removes the formula (keeps only the value) if you select any cell in range "n4:o25", but if you select something else it does nothing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Rng As Range
Static Cell As Range
Set Rng = Range("n4:o25")
  If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Rng) Is Nothing Then
    Set Cell = ActiveCell
    If Not Cell Is Nothing Then
      Cell.Value = Cell.Value
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: MASHA'ALLAH! Thank you so much sir! Code is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

You have after `if`:

```
    Set Cell = ActiveCell
```

but that is missing in your `else` part.